# Trying to write sort method

Tags: ruby, sorting, methods, recursion

Trying to sort an array by writing my own sort method using recursion (Pine's book). Saw some other examples on stackoverflow, but my code looks different from them. Two things I don't understand so far:

1. What is a wrapper method, and why do I need one? (I put on in the code, I think).
2. How to fix the "stack level too deep" error.

**EDIT: New code updated, working but not correct.**

Here's what I have so far:

```
def word_sorter unsorted, sorted
  if unsorted[1] == nil
    sorted.push unsorted[0]
    words_put(sorted)
  elsif unsorted[0] <= unsorted[1]
    sorted.push unsorted[0]
    unsorted.shift
    word_sorter(unsorted, sorted)
  else
    unsorted.push unsorted[0]
    unsorted.shift
    word_sorter(unsorted, sorted)
  end
end

def words_put sorted
  puts 'these are your words now organized.'
  sorted.compact!
  puts sorted.join(', ')
  Process.exit
end

unsorted = Array.new
sorted = Array.new
puts 'list as many words as you want. I will sort them... I think'
while unsorted.last != ''
  unsorted.push gets.chomp
  if unsorted.last == ''
    unsorted.pop
    word_sorter(unsorted, sorted)
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: what sorting algorithm are you trying to implement?

Comment: "Wrapper method" is not a Ruby term. Presumably it refers to a method that doesn't do anything else but call a different method in a specific way. As for "Stack level too deep," that probably means your recursion is happening infinitely, which means your mechanism for ending the recursion is never happening.

Comment: Using two arrays, one which had the original words in the order presented by the gets, and then checking words next to each other to get the order correct in the sorted array. It should always push the "lowest" (a first, then b, etc) word, until the highest word is left, which is then finally pushed to the sorted array.

Comment: Please try your algorithm on `[2,3,1]`. It will fail to run correctly unless you define `[2,1,3]` to be sorted ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first try your code by some simple examples. E.g. use the list `[3,2,1]` as input.

In the first call it will match the `3>=2` condition. Thus now `sorted=[2]`.

There are two issues with this one already.

1. `2` isn't the first entry in the sorted list. There must be an issue with your algorithm being not able to sort any input.
2. The array `unsorted` isn't changed at all and thus it will loop with this one forever, yielding `sorted=[2,2,2,2,2.....]`.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up researching different sort algorithms, and made the first one I found: bubble sort. I posted the result on my blog, and 2,3,1 works in it. I figured out that the original code was telling me  that 2 is lower than 3, but it isn't the lowest. Is there a way to use the min method to just find the lowest string and push to a new array?

Comment: @podopie `['AXYZ', 'ABC', 'DEF'].min` gives you `'ABC'`

Answer (score 2):

1) There is nothing special going on here. We are using plain English (albeit metaphorically). A wrapper method is a method which is a wrapper. A wrapper is a thing which wraps. You are wrapping the `word_sorter` method with the `sort` method. You "need" it for convenience: it would be strange for the `sort` method to expect an empty list for its second parameter when you call it from outside. The wrapping takes into account the fact that the obvious interface for the recursion differs from the obvious interface for the outside world.

2) Take a close look at how the code for handling `unsorted[0] >= unsorted[1]` differs from the `else` case (i.e. when `unsorted[0] < unsorted[1]`).

3) Try describing your algorithm in English first. And then try putting out a few playing cards and testing your algorithm by following it, to the letter.

4) A working sort algorithm will only need to be called once. So work out a proper sorting algorithm, and then only call it once - outside the loop, after you've read in all the values to sort. You might also want to actually call `words_put`.

Comment: Awesome! Realized the real problem was that I was using the wrong array method: ary.drop does not work the same as ary.shift, which is what I really wanted. Some other editing makes it work great, except now it keeps going back to the gets.chomp after it puts the words. Thanks!

Comment: Again, the `unsorted.push gets.chomp` part should be the only thing inside the loop. The sort call and the display call should go after the loop. To do otherwise is to abuse the loop's semantics.

Comment: Could you share the code rewrite? I took the code from the original sort program that I wrote when I was still using the built in sort method.

Answer (score 0):

"Stack level too deep" implies that you have infinite recursion going on.  It doesn't look like the unsorted list gets shorter in any of your branches in word_sorter, so it will keep running forever.